# Which version of a native apex class is used?

Tags: apex, api-version

We have a scenario where our somewhat complex apex code hierarchy is calling Database.Update.  This returns an instance of a list of SaveResult.  The documentation for SaveResult says this about the method getId():

> Prior to API version 53.0, the method returned a null value if the
> record wasn’t updated successfully. In API version 53.0 and later, the
> method returns the sObject ID, regardless of whether the update
> operation is successful or not.

So we are trying to use the post V53 functionality, and are updating all the apex classes in our calling stack to use V53 or above.  And yet we are still seeing the pre V53 behavior i.e. on a failure, getId() returns null. So my question is: when mixing apex classes from multiple versions, which version is used for the standard provided classes?  Is it the version of the custom apex class which directly calls the provided class, or something else?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think using the term "native class" is confusing. "Standard provided classes" or "Salesforce-provided classes" is probably the more common terminology.

Comment: Do you have some reproducible code that demonstrates this behavior? This would help us figure out if you've got a bug, or just some quirk with how you're calling the code.

Comment: @sfdcfox That's one of the problems, the code leading up to the final call is too complex to easily display or reproduce.  Rather than fix the issue, I'm trying to see under what circumstances the pre V53 functionality would be used.

Comment: @hamayoun Have you tried generating a debug log? The first few lines will likely explain the problem in more detail than even code would. Just open the Salesforce Developer Console, perform your action, and check the log file in the Logs tab. The very first line gives you a hint about what version you're using and flags are set, and the next few lines should point you tot he offending component, which may not be code at all.

Comment: AFAIK, the save results are initialized with values in the context of the call to `Database.update`. Thus the version in the class that does the update should control what you get. Of course, there is a chance there is some deferred processing behind this specific API, in which case it could be the code that calls methods on the save result API thay provides the version context. I cannot see it be anything else.